# Angular app renders a blank page after successful compile

Tags: angular

error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined
    at Object../node_modules/firebase/auth.js (auth.js:295)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Module../node_modules/angularfire2/auth/auth.js (auth.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Module../node_modules/angularfire2/auth.js (auth.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Module../src/app/app.module.ts (app.component.ts:8)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Module../src/main.ts (environment.ts:26)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
```

Comment: I need a few more information about versions of angular and angularfire2 inside of package.json and also some code of main.ts and environment.ts.

Could you post them as well?

Comment: "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
    "angularfire2": "^4.0.0-rc.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "firebase": "^4.2.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.3",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"

Comment: main.tsimport { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));

Answer (score 0):

It seems your version of angularfire is outdated for your version of angular, since angular 8, angular fire is included inside angular itself:
To install it you could use:
`npm install firebase @angular/fire --save`

Have a look at https://www.positronx.io/firebase-authentication-in-angular-8-with-angularfire2/ for more information - there it is pretty good explained.